# Having 2 git remotes, one with git lfs the other without

Tags: git, binaryfiles, git-remote

I have a tricky situation. I have a project, there are 2 remotes, a personal gitlab remote and a remote hosted by my organization.

It seems the organization git server cannot handle/ does not have git-lfs. I only need to submit to the organization's git repo to make sure there is a copy accessible to other people. I don't use that server regularly.

Is there  a way to configure git with to remotes so that my gitlab remote uses git-lfs regularly but the organization remote ignores all git-lfs files and pretends they don't exist?